# How do I output the value to terminal

Tags: gcc

```
nBytes = usb_control_msg(handle, USB_TYPE_VENDOR | USB_RECIP_DEVICE | USB_ENDPOINT_IN, PSCMD_ANGRY_ON, 0, 0, (char *)buffer, sizeof(buffer), 5000);
int isOn = buffer[0];
```

I'm trying to output the element 0 of the buffer.

Tried `iostream` but gcc couldn't find library. I do have `stdlibs` installed via `Ubuntu` repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use printf...

```
printf("%c", buffer[0]);
```

Comment: Probably better off using `"%d"` or `"0x%x"`. There's no guarantee `buffer` is ASCII characters.